# Can I safely remove cinnamon if I have i3?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, window-manager, i3

I installed i3 and want to remove cinnamon to stop getting the prompt at startup to choose a window manager. Is it safe to sudo apt-get purge cinnamon? Or what would be the best way to do this? Thank you.

Distributor ID: LinuxMint

Description:    Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia

Release:    19.3

Codename:   tricia

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get remove` is safer. It won't remove configuration files, that you may have changed. So easier to change your mind. The only worry that I would have is that it may cause the display-manager(thing that allows you to login) to be removed. It using the old display-manager, then do an install on it (or mark it as manually installed), so that it is not removed.